# Invoke-WmiMethod behaving different on Win8(PS3.0) and Win7(PS2.0)

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-2.0

I'm gonna copy paste some code here from an answer I just made for a SO question. The problem I'm having is why `Invoke-WmiMethod` returns an error on my windows 7(PS2.0) machine while working on windows 8(PS3.0). Here's the code:

```
#Username/Group to give permissions to
$trustee = ([wmiclass]'Win32_trustee').psbase.CreateInstance()
$trustee.Domain = "domainname"
$trustee.Name = "username"

#Accessmask values
$fullcontrol = 2032127
$change = 1245631
$read = 1179785

#Create access-list
$ace = ([wmiclass]'Win32_ACE').psbase.CreateInstance()
$ace.AccessMask = $fullcontrol
$ace.AceFlags = 3
$ace.AceType = 0
$ace.Trustee = $trustee

#Securitydescriptor containting access
$sd = ([wmiclass]'Win32_SecurityDescriptor').psbase.CreateInstance()
$sd.ControlFlags = 4
$sd.DACL = $ace
$sd.group = $trustee
$sd.owner = $trustee

#Arguments - Arguments: access, description, max. allowed, name, password, path, type(0 = drive/folder share)
Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Share -Name Create -ArgumentList @($sd, "TestDescription", 100, "TestName$", "", "C:\Test", 0)
```

`Invoke-WmiMethod` returns an error when executed on a windows 7 machine, while working fine on windows 8. If I replace `$sd` (access paramter) with $null it runs fine on win7. The error is:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod <<<< -Class win32_share -name Create -ArgumentList @($sd, "TestDescription", 100, "TestName$", "", "C:\Test", 0) 
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-WmiMethod], ManagementException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWmiMethod'
```

This is the parameter-list that's used by `Invoke-WmiMethod`:

```
PS C:\Windows> ([wmiclass]'win32_share').GetMethodParameters('create')

__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 7
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
Access           : 
Description      : 
MaximumAllowed   : 
Name             : 
Password         : 
Path             : 
Type             : 
PSComputerName   :
```

Can anyone help me understand why `Invoke-WmiMethod` doesn't like my access parameter on w7, while working on w8? It accepts `$sd` on both if I run it with: `([wmiclass]'Win32_share').Create(.....)` using it's definition:

```
PS C:\Windows> ([wmiclass]'win32_share').Create

OverloadDefinitions   
-------------------                                             
System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Create(System.String Path, System.String Name, System.UInt32 Type, System.UInt32 MaximumAllowed, System.String Description, System
.String Password, System.Management.ManagementObject#Win32_SecurityDescriptor Access)
```